# Searching for emojis in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, emoji, utf8mb4

I have a string that looks like this:

[image: Six emojis in a row]

Now, when my app shoves this string into its utf8 mysql database column, it looks like this in the MySQL CLI:

[image: String representation]

If I select `convert(mystring using utfmb4)` it still looks like this.

And if I turn it to hex using `select hex(mystring) from mytable;`, it looks like this:

`C3A2CB9CE282ACC3AFC2B8C28FC3B0C5B8C592CB86C3B0C5B8C592C5A0C3B0C5B8C592C281C3B0C5B8E280A1C2ACC3B0C5B8E280A1C2A7`

Now, let's say I want to find strings with that emoji wave in it. Well, the hex for the wave emoji is `F09F8C8A`. But `F09F8C8A` isn't in the hex above so something like `select * from mytable where hex(mystring) like '%F09F8C8A%';` doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45421034/842935

Answer (score 1):

I call that "double encoding".  Your client claimed it was getting latin1 characters, but told MySQL that they should be utf8, so a 3-byte utf8 character got converted to 6 bytes in the database.

You need to fix both the client and the data in the table(s).  <strike>This link discusses it:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll . (Sorry, there is no brief summary of how to fix your problems.)</strike>  The [*issues*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) and the [*fixes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases).