# MySQL query not working through PHP with non English character

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a MySQL query in PHP when I'm having non English language, it is always returning 0 rows. The query is pretty straight forward and here is the relevant snippet.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT ID, post_content FROM udhay.posts WHERE post_content = 'இ'";
$query = $conn->query($sql);

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_R($row);die;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results \n\n";
}
```

The only odd thing you could find here is the WHERE condition is having a Tamil character.

I checked even the MySQL error log and found that the right query got executed and tried that query once again directly in the MySQL and it is working perfectly. Also I tried with some English letters and words and it is completely working fine without any issues.

**Version Info:**

```
MySQL: 
    mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
PHP: 
    PHP 5.6.28 (cli) (built: Dec 22 2016 01:56:27) 
    Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Any clue on this or solution would really be great.

Comment: You seem to rely in the default encoding of everything. That's very risky. You should use a proper encoding explicitly, probably UTF-8.

Comment: character encoding of the table may be different than utf-8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147829/how-can-i-search-by-emoji-in-mysql-using-utf8mb4 --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462979/searching-for-emojis-in-mysql - kind of seems related.

Comment: @YamanJain The character encoding is utf8_general_ci

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm using LAMP, MySQL version 5.7.18

Comment: @Fred-ii- I really donlt have any problem when I execute the query directly in MySQL, but this is happening only when I go through PHP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through your answers are all probably in there. Pass the connection as utf-8 first and file encoding, etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep, you are absolutely right. That's the issue. You saved my day. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @Stranger *Cheers*